# This undefined in fat arrow function but is defined in the enclosing scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to do something fairly simple:

I have a function that is part of a class, in the function I call an
async method and I use the `.then` syntax to listen for its completion. I
then use an arrow function to perform an action.

This is where something goes wrong, inside my arrow function, `this`
is undefined according to the VS Code debugger. But, `this` is defined in the function
(`write(document)`) containing the arrow function.

Here is the code for that:

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const path = require('path');

class DB {

    constructor(name) {
        this.db = path.normalize("./");
    }

    write(document) {
        const dir = path.normalize(this.db + "/" + document);
        fs.exists(dir).then((exists) => {
            console.log(this); // ADDED THIS IN EDIT.
            if (!exists) {
                return fs.mkdir(dir)
            } else {
                return new Promise();
            }
        }).then(() => {
            const file = path.normalize(dir + "/" + document + ".json");
            fs.readFile(file, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I thought to have read that the arrow function automatically binds `this` from the scope where the arrow function defined is. But perhaps I misunderstood? I work mainly with Dart in which the scope rules aren't as complicated so perhaps I am mixing something up with Dart?

**--EDIT--**
Sorry for the confusion, I actually didn't need `this` in my arrow function but was just surprised that the VS Code debugger showed it as `undefined`. I now added a console log in the arrow function and apparently it is defined! Thus perhaps there is something wrong with the VS Code Node debugger? So after all, there doesn't seem to be a problem with the code anyways...
[image]

Comment: You have three different arrow functions and none of them attempts to use `this`. It's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: "This is where something goes wrong…" — You've marked this up as a quotation. Who are you quoting? If it isn't a quote, please don't use quote markup.

Comment: @Quentin I actually do not need `this` in any of the arrow functions, but upon debugging I found that `this` is undefined in their scope for some reason. So I would like to know why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three different arrow functions and none of them attempts to use `this`.

> I actually do not need this in any of the arrow functions, but upon debugging I found that this is undefined in their scope for some reason.

This is a performance optimisation.

If a variable isn't used in a function then it will not exist in that function, even if it would otherwise be in scope.

This allows, for example:

```
function foo () {
    var bar = something_that_returns_a_memory_intensive_object()
    return () => console.log(1);
}

const baz = foo();
```

After `foo` has finished running and returns its function, `bar` (and the large object) can be garbage collected.

The same is true of `this`.

> I now added a console log in the arrow function and apparently it is defined!

… and when you use it, the variable is closed over and made available.

Comment: "If a variable isn't used in a function then it will not exist in that function, even if it would otherwise be in scope."
I did not know that! Anyways, I added `console.log(this)` so I guess it is used now. The `console.log()` prints out the actual object as it is supposed to BUT the VS Code debugger still shows `this` as `undefined`. Is that expected behavior?

Comment: @BramVanbilsen — It isn't the behaviour I would expect, but I can reproduce it.